# Stairstep Div Formatting

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a client who wants a particular design on their home page to match what is seen on their magazine cover.  The basic stairstep design of the cover never changes but occasionally the images do.  I have not been able to devise a way to cover this format without using 1 large image.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z6ghY/

Note: The appearance in this fiddle is correct in how the client wants it to be seen.  My problem is that it uses one large image that must be changed occasionally.  It would be much easier if these three images were separated.

Anyone know the best way I can achieve this?  The images can be placed via HTML or CSS, either way does not matter, though it would be nice to see them in the HTML for SEO benefits.

In case the fiddle doesn't display the image here it is.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxJet.png

HTML:

```
<h2>Innovative Engineering Solutions in Material Handling</h2>

<div class="home-container">
<div class="home-content"><p>Experience the impact that Lauyans &amp; Company can make on your business success.  Through innovative engineering solutions in material handling, Lauyans will take responsibility for the planning, execution and acceptance of your project.</p>

<!--h2>Lauyans... why choose anyone else?</h2-->


<h2 style="margin: 80px 0 0 30px;">Lauyans...<br />  why choose<br />  anyone else?</h2>


</div><!-- END HOME CONTENT -->

</div><!-- END HOME CONTAINER -->

<div class="home-container2">
<div class="home-planning">
<h3>Planning</h3>
</div>
<div class="home-execution">
<h3>Execution</h3>
</div>
<div class="home-acceptance">
<h3>Acceptance</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home-container { width: 690px; height: 459px; background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/home-image.png') 50% 100% no-repeat; }
.home-container2 { width: 690px; }
.home-content { width: 430px; height: 429px; padding: 15px; }
.home-content p { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.home-content h2 { padding-top: 10px; margin: 0; }
.home-container2 h3 { padding-top: 0px; margin: 0; text-align: center; }
.home-planning { width: 230px; float: left; }
.home-execution { width: 230px; float: left; }
.home-acceptance { width: 230px; float: left; }
```

Comment: I don't see any image in the fiddle...

Comment: It did not work?  It shows for me.  here is the direct link: http://i.imgur.com/6s2i9L7.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the absolute positioning route considering the "unique" layout you are going for:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6ghY/1/

I reworked everything (including the images which I had to grab from somewhere else):

HTML

```
<div class="home_con">

    <h2 class="pge_title">Innovative Kitten Solutions</h2>

    <div class="home_step">
        <h2 class="step-title">Lauyans...<br />  why choose<br />  anyone else?</h2>

        <p>
            Experience the impact that Kittens can make on your business success through
            purring.
        </p>   

        <img class="img1" src="http://www.vivapets.com/img/album/52/19052_white_persian_kittens_for_adoption_thb.jpg" />

        <img class="img2" src="http://www.saudivets.com/images/Vpic20.jpg" />   

        <img class="img3" src="http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/167/2/8/kitten_tracks_banner_100x300_by_xxjessie_kittehxx-d3j2h51.png" />

    </div>

    <div class="img_text">
        <div class="img_text_ele">Planning</div>
        <div class="img_text_ele">Execution</div>
        <div class="img_text_ele">Acceptance</div>
    </div> 

</div>
```

CSS

```
.home_con h2.pge_title { font-weight:bold; font-size:1.125em; }

.home_step { width:300px; height:300px; position:relative; }
.home_step h2.step-title { position:absolute; top:110px; left:10px; }
.home_step p { width:200px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; }
.home_step img { position:absolute; bottom:0px; }
.home_step .img1 { left;0px; }
.home_step .img2 { left:100px; }
.home_step .img3 { left:200px; }

.home_con .img_text { width:300px; overflow:hidden; }
.home_con .img_text_ele { width:100px; float:left; text-align:center; }
```

Comment: This should work in IE without any issues as far as I can tell too.  Thank you!  This is exactly what I was needing.

Comment: Hmmm... See the link below for this solution in practice...  What is causing it to stray above the page?

http://engineered.walkupright.com/

Answer (score 0):

This way would need the images to be chopped up a bit but it would work if that was cool to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/5qfLj/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">1</div>
        <div class="span1" style="background:#ccc;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span1">3</div>
        <div class="span1"  style="background:#666;">4</div>
        <div class="span1"  style="background:#ccc;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span1" style="background:#999;">5</div>
        <div class="span1" style="background:#666;">6</div>
        <div class="span1" style="background:#ccc;">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:600px;
}

.row {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.span1 {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.span2 {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I thought about that as a solution initially but it would be ideal if the images could be replaced through a size template without having to crop them in half etc.